# How do I get the remote's signal strength in the DJI Windows SDK?

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I was able to find the GPS signal strength method and event in the FlightControllerHandler but for the life of me I can't find the equivalent for the remote's signal strength.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted DJI support and they informed me that this functionality is not currently in the API but it may be considered in the future.